# how to know the exact table a result is coming from after using UNION to create a searchfield for two or more different tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a search field for a website and this search field is supposed to search the whole website, so I have been able to search my whole website by using the keyword UNION in MySQL to query the four tables in my website for a result.

however, when the result is back and I try to create a link so that I can display the full article. It is impossible because PHP seems not to understand the table where the result is coming from.

When I click on the link, it only brings an empty page without the result set. when I tried this again by not using UNION and using the result from just a single table it worked just fine, once I click on the result from the search field it redirects me directly to where the full article is located, But with the trying to combine multiple tables by using union, it only goes blank when I click on the link(the result from the search field) I'll appreciate the help of you guys  thanks
here is my source code below

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['search']);
    $sql = "(SELECT id, artistname, lastedited, label, details,fullname AS title FROM artist  WHERE artistname LIKE '%$search%' OR fullname LIKE '%$search%' OR details LIKE '%$search%' OR label LIKE '%$search%')
     UNION
            (SELECT id, headline, time, date, newsbody,author AS title FROM news  WHERE date LIKE '%$search%' OR headline LIKE '%$search%' OR newsbody LIKE '%$search%' OR author LIKE '%$search%')
     UNION
            (SELECT id, tracktitle, ftartist, lyrics, details,dor AS title FROM track  WHERE tracktitle LIKE '%$search%' OR ftartist LIKE '%$search%' OR lyrics LIKE '%$search%' OR details LIKE '%$search%')
     UNION
            (SELECT id, albumtitle, artist, tracks, albumdetails,ftartist AS title FROM album  WHERE albumtitle LIKE '%$search%' OR artist LIKE '%$search%' OR ftartist LIKE '%$search%' OR albumdetails LIKE '%$search%')
    ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $result_per_page = 10;
    $number_of_pages = ceil($queryResult/$result_per_page);

            if(!isset($_GET['page'])){               
            $page = 1;
        }else{
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }

        $this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$result_per_page;

    if($queryResult > 0){
        echo "There are ".$queryResult." results!";
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "YOUR SEARCH NOT HERE?"; 
        echo "<a href = 'index.php'>";
        echo " try another keyword";
        echo "</a>";
    }


    if ($queryResult > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "<a href = 'article.php?title=".$row['title']."&date= ".$row['lastedited']."'>
                                <div class = 'article-box'>
                                <h3>".$row['artistname']."</h3>
                                <p>".$row['details']."</p>
                                <p>".$row['label']."</p>
                                <p>".$row['lastedited']."</p>
                        </div></a>";

            }
    } else {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "There are no results matching your search!";
        echo "<a href = 'index.php'>";
        echo " back home";
        echo "</a>";
}
```

Comment: Include the source in the result: select 'table1' source, columns from table1

Comment: @Strawberry Can you kindly expatiate. source in what sense? I don't really understand your comment and I really need help on this, I will appreciate it if you can help out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I'm seriously advocating this as a solution, but here's one idea...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movies;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cheeses;

CREATE TABLE movies(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE cheeses(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,cheese VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO movies (title) VALUES ("Raiders of the Lost Ark"),("Ferris Bueller's Day Off"),("Jaws"),("La La Land"),("Bladerunner"),("Casablanca");
INSERT INTO cheeses (cheese) VALUES ("Edam"),("Gruyere"),("Cheddar"),("Manchego"),("Gouda"),("Camembert");

SELECT * FROM movies;
+----+--------------------------+
| id | title                    |
+----+--------------------------+
|  1 | Raiders of the Lost Ark  |
|  2 | Ferris Bueller's Day Off |
|  3 | Jaws                     |
|  4 | La La Land               |
|  5 | Bladerunner              |
|  6 | Casablanca               |
+----+--------------------------+

SELECT * FROM cheeses;
+----+-----------+
| id | cheese    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Edam      |
|  2 | Gruyere   |
|  3 | Cheddar   |
|  4 | Manchego  |
|  5 | Gouda     |
|  6 | Camembert |
+----+-----------+

SELECT x.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT 'movies' source_table, 'title' source_column, title value FROM movies
        UNION
       SELECT 'cheeses', 'cheese', cheese FROM cheeses
     ) x
 WHERE value IN ('Camembert','Casablanca');

+--------------+---------------+------------+
| source_table | source_column | value      |
+--------------+---------------+------------+
| movies       | title         | Casablanca |
| cheeses      | cheese        | Camembert  |
+--------------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: +1 but FWIW you don't need to define column aliases for the second or later terms in a UNION. The column names are set by the first term. Not that this has anything to do with your answer, I'm just sharing trivia. :)

Comment: @BillKarwin You're quite right - but that's copy-paste for you ;-)